# ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are using SQL 2005 Express for storage.

I am using ODBCCommand to update some values in my table but getting the error below.  Table has all valid columns.

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
```

So please let me know what issue with it, the query working fine in SQL Browser.

My code:

```
cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE Transaction_Details SET SubscriptionCancelled=? WHERE SubscriptionID=?", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubscriptionCancelled", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = "Subscription Cancelled on " + DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubscriptionID", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = sSubscriptionID;
```

Comment: What is the CommandType of your ODBCCommand object?

Comment: why are you using OdbcCommand rather than SqlCommand?

Comment: I'd like to point out that it seems unnecessary to me to have "Subscription Cancelled on " as part of the data stored in the SubscriptionCanceled column. If the column is already called SubscriptionCancelled (there's already meaning in that name), I'd make that a datetime column and just store the date; otherwise, you are going to have a difficult time in the future querying that table for dates when subscriptions were cancelled. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @mitch - I undeleted so he can test, but I'm not sure.  I checked the msdn info and in the one sample I found they didn't delimit.  However they also didn't concatenate the string

Comment: @JNK: :(  I think you're right. no adornment appears to be required...

Comment: @mitch - well I'll leave it til he can test.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used ODBCcommand before, but I'm guessing you need to delimit your strings with single quotes in the command statement.

Try changing to:

```
cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE Transaction_Details SET SubscriptionCancelled='?' WHERE SubscriptionID='?'", conn);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the right answer since the column you are trying to update is a varchar, and that needs to be in single quotes in normal T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
UPDATE Transaction_Details SET SubscriptionCancelled=? WHERE SubscriptionID=?
```

to

```
UPDATE Transaction_Details SET SubscriptionCancelled=@SubscriptionCancelled WHERE SubscriptionID=@SubscriptionID
```

Comment: that's what I originally thought but you don't need to. it substitutes in parameter '?' order...

Comment: BTW: guys, if you use SSMS and haven't downloaded Mladen Prajdic's SSMS Tools Pack, I strongly suggest you do. It's very, very useful....

Answer (score 0):

Given that SQL doesn't know the type of your parameters, because you are building a T-SQL statement rather then using a parameterised query, perhaps quotes are needed around your strings?

I haven't had an opportunity to test this, but it's a quick suggestion to try out.